# How can I support "checkout - build - run" when loading requires third party applications or plugins?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, msbuild, continuous-integration

Sometimes (often?) a project requires dependencies on local installations of third party tools to be able to compile. One such dependency is [MS Build Tasks from Tigris](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/), but we encounter others as well.

We try to follow the **principle of least surprise**: *checkout - open solution - build - run*. If the build cannot trigger the install of a third party tool, this doesn't work. Worse, sometimes a `csproj` file has these dependencies and causes load failure errors in Visual Studio.

One solution is to add an setup-visualstudio.txt file, but that's sub-ideal.

What I'd really like is a sanity check upon loading the solution, or right after checking out, **that informs the user that in order to successfully build or load the project, he needs to install software X.** Other than building this ourselves, what are common practices to deal with this?

Comment: Have you looked at Nuget for package management?

Comment: @Nick: can NuGet take car of that kind of issues?

Comment: well nuget allows you to define the 3rd party dependencies you have and automate the deployment of them within a solution at build time. You can create your own nuget pkgs and host them on your own deployment location for finer grained control as well.

Comment: checkout nuget.org and read up!

Comment: @Nick: Sounds like that helps on situations where we currently actually use NuGet, i.e. on build. It doesn't help for dependencies in projects that fail loading the project file itself. But, maybe we can externalize these dependencies and use NuGet as bootstrap. Hmm.

Comment: Check out http://chocolatey.org/ for a variant on nuget that allows for you to script your way into prerequisite installation using the same mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(a much belated answer by myself)*

The solution, applied on many projects I have had since, use either NuGet or Paket for solving external dependencies. You can host your own NuGet if you have packages that are not available publicly, this is quite easy to setup.

This idea is courtesy of Nick in the comments. Note his mention of [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/), which is certainly helpful in some scenarios.